# Increasing performance of a function which processes an array using destructuring and recursion

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I wanted to create a function which takes another function and an array as parameters and calls that function for each three consecutive elements of the array (e.g. first, second and third; second, third and forth). I implemented it using destructuring and recursion. However, I found out that it has terrible performance – it takes about 100 ms to process a 1000-element array, and uses a lot of memory. Here's a code snippet:

```js
const eachThree = fn => ([first, second, third, ...rest]) => {
  fn(first, second, third);
  if (rest.length !== 0) {
    eachThree(fn)([second, third, ...rest]);
  }
};

const noop = () => {};
const arr = Array(1000).fill(undefined);

console.time('eachThree');
eachThree(noop)(arr);
console.timeEnd('eachThree');
```

I'm aware that to increase performance I could just use a regular for loop, but is it possible to modify this function somehow to make it faster while keeping destructuring and recursion?

Also, are there any plans to optimize JavaScript engines to make code like this run faster? Would tail-call optimization solve this?

Comment: `eachThree` not in a tail-call position, so even if TCO was implemented it wouldn't be optimised.

Comment: @zerkms It is, all it would need is a `return` in front. (Though pedantically, it's not the `eachTree` function itself but the closure it returns that will get the optimisation of course)

Comment: @Bergi but then it's a new function generated every run (recursion iteration). Not sure how smart the runtime must be to be able to infer that those different functions are similar. But I'm sure the standard does not cover this case.

Comment: @zerkms Tail calls are (should be, according to the standard) optimised regardless which function is called. It doesn't matter whether it's a recursive function calling itself, or anything else. Notice that only the stack growth is optimised away, not the whole call - although inlining *might* even do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it takes about 100 ms to process a 1000-element array, and uses a lot of memory.

The reason for that is obviously the destructuring and spread syntax, which creates 2000 arrays with an average size of 500 elements. That ain't cheap.

> I'm aware that to increase performance I could just use a regular for loop, but is it possible to modify this function somehow to make it faster while keeping destructuring and recursion?

Giving up the destructuring (in favour of an index, like in @Sylwester's answer) would be the best solution, but there's indeed a few things other things you can optimise:

- Use `return` to allow for tail call optimisation (if the engine supports it)
- Cache the inner function instead of re-creating the closure with the same `fn` over and over again.

```
const eachThree = fn => {
  const eachThreeFn = ([first, second, third, ...rest]) => {
    fn(first, second, third);
    if (rest.length !== 0) {
      return eachThreeFn([second, third, ...rest]);
    }
  };
  return eachThreeFn;
};
```

Comment: Is it possible that in the future creating arrays with destructuring and spread syntax will be more optimized? Because for example a similar function in Haskell: `eachThree f (x:y:z:zs) = (f x y z) : eachThree f (y:z:zs)` seems to be working fine.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski Haskell uses immutable linked lists, which are *very* different from JS arrays. Of course it might be possible to optimise destructuring/spread syntax if it the optimiser can proof none of the arrays are mutated, but I don't think it'll happen.

Answer (score 2):

So I hope for your and our sake you really need to shave off those 200ms since it doesn't seem like a real life problem to me. Know that in the rules of optimization:

1. Don't
2. Don't
3. Profile so you know were to optimize.

When it comes to optimization neatness and style goes out of the window. That means you can throw out recursion. In this case however, it's not the recursion that is your biggest problem but the 2n arrays you are making.
Here is a slightly faster version:

```js
const eachThree = fn => arr => {
  const maxLen = arr.length-3;
  const recur = (n) => {
    fn(arr[n], arr[n+1], arr[n+2]);
    if (n < maxLen) {
      recur(n+1);
    }
  }; 
  recur(0);
};
```

Now ES6 has proper tail calls and Node6 has implemented this. It runs about 400 times faster than your original code when I test it there. Not that you will notice the change IRL.

Comment: "When it comes to optimization neatness and style goes out of the window." – in Haskell a similar function works fine, so I thought that maybe it could work in JavaScript too. Regarding "it doesn't seem like a real life problem to me" – the array has only 1000 elements, and in real life it could have much more.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski The whole loop as it is written is dead code so if you would have ported it to C it might have been optimized away. Haskell might either also optimize it away or just not run it until you use the value since it's inherently lazy. Usually I make rest calls that takes seconds so  100ms isn't very long time.

Comment: how is this not neat ?

Comment: @Sikorski When optimizing it's not required to make the code unreadable, but certain features like destructuring, which the OP didn't want to loose, had to go so in that sense it's a little less neat. IRL optimized code might not look as neat and I have cases where the original neat version is left commented out above as documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem open to refactoring the code, here's a pretty dramatic rewrite that performs the same task about 10x faster (using your means of benchmarking)

I think you'll appreciate that a very functional style has been maintained

```js
const drop = (n,xs) =>
  xs.slice(n)

const take = (n,xs) =>
  xs.slice(0,n)

const slide = (x,y) => xs =>
  x > xs.length
    ? []
    : [take (x,xs)] .concat (slide (x,y) (drop (y,xs)))

const eachThree = f => xs =>
  slide (3,1) (xs) .forEach (([a,b,c]) => f (a,b,c))

const noop = () => {}

const arr = Array(1000).fill(undefined)

console.time('eachThree')
eachThree(noop)(arr)
console.timeEnd('eachThree')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a trampoline solves the memory usage problem, but it doesn't speed up the code. Here's a code snippet:

```js
const trampoline = fn => {
  do {
    fn = fn();
  } while (typeof fn === 'function');
};

const eachThree = fn => ([first, second, third, ...rest]) => () => {
  fn(first, second, third);
  if (rest.length !== 0) {
    return eachThree(fn)([second, third, ...rest]);
  }
};

const noop = () => {};
const arr = Array(5000).fill(undefined);

console.time('eachThree');
trampoline(eachThree(noop)(arr));
console.timeEnd('eachThree');
```

Comment: I think it's not an answer then.

Comment: @zerkms Well, it solves one of the problems, so I think it is at least a partial answer.